# Collapsing and reopening a React accordion resets the internal states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, tailwind-css, setstate

I'm working with a ReactJS accordion component where I render forms inside each section. However, when I collapse and then expand the accordion, all form inputs reset to their default values. This seems to be triggered by a re-render when the `isOpen` state changes. How can I preserve the form states while still maintaining the accordion's functionality?"

I have defined the forms states in the parent file where the `<Accordion {...props}/>` is used and sent the `setState` function as props. The setState is called inside the form component

Accordioin Component

```
export default function Accordian({
  title,
  content,
  children,
  headingPrefixIcon,
  headingSuffixIcon,
  fontSize = 'medium',
  textSize = 'lg',
  customizableClassProps = 'border-t',
  showToggle = false,
  showBadge,
  badgeText,
  isCollapsible = true,
  taggleEnable,
  setTaggleEnable,
  useAccordianStateForToggle = false
}) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  const toggleAccordion = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  }

  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className='border border-gray-200 rounded-base mb-2 w-full'>
      <div
        className='flex justify-between items-center p-3 cursor-pointer bg-[#F9F8FD] rounded-base select-none'
        onClick={toggleAccordion}
      >
        <div className='flex items-center gap-2'>
          <div>{headingPrefixIcon}</div>
          <h2
            className={`text-${textSize} font-${fontSize} text-app-description`}
          >
            {title}
          </h2>
          <div>{headingSuffixIcon}</div>
        </div>
        {isCollapsible ?
          !showToggle ? (
            isOpen ? (
              <ChevronUpIcon className='w-6 h-6' />
            ) : (
              <ChevronDownIcon className='w-6 h-6' />
            )
          ) : (<FlyyToggle enabled={!useAccordianStateForToggle ? taggleEnable : isOpen} setEnabled={!useAccordianStateForToggle ? setTaggleEnable : setIsOpen} sort />) : showBadge ? <FlyyBadge size={"small"} rounded grey badgeText={badgeText} /> : <div />}
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className={`p-3 ${customizableClassProps} border-gray-200`}>
          {content || children}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The forms are rendered through the `content` props.

I have tried initializing states in the parent file, still facing the same issue.

If you need any other detail please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep forms in the page you could use css to show or hide it, avoiding to destroying it every time you close the accordion.

```js
<div className={`${isOpen ? '' : 'hidden'} p-3 ${customizableClassProps} border-gray-200`}>
  {content || children}
</div>
```

Comment: Holy shit dude, amazing thank you so much